Is it safe to delete self-energy files SystemLabel.TSGF* during transport properties calculations at different bias values?
Siesta stopped because of running out of disk space in my workstation during transport properties calculations at different bias values.
I would like to calculate transport properties for bias values from 0.0 V to 2.5 V at a step of 0.1 V. However, siesta stopped at  0.6 V because of running out of disk space. I found there were very large files SystemLabel.TSGFLeft and  SystemLabel.TSGFRight generated at each bias value calculation. Is it safe to delete these files and continue to calculate transport properties from where it stopped?
Any suggestions will be appreciated!

I found these files generated at one bias value will not be used by calculations at other bias values and TBtrans. Therefore, it should be safe to delete these files immediately after finishing calculations at each bias value.
As the manual states:
SystemLabel.TSGF*: Self-energy files containing the used self-energies from the leads. These are
very large files used in the SCF loop. Once completed one can safely delete these files. For
heavily increased throughput these files may be re-used for the same electrode settings in
various calculations.

